# Knockout won't update string array in model made with ko.mapping

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here is jsfiddle with a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/a28aP/5/

Viewmodel:

```
{
 "pitalice": [{
     "pitanje": "Kako se zove rezultat koji se dobija deljenjem dva broja",
     "ponudjeno": ["Kolicnik", "Suma", "Proizvod"],
     "tacan": 0
 }, {
     "pitanje": "Limonit je ruda",
     "ponudjeno": ["Aluminijuma", "Olova", "Gvožda"],
     "tacan": 2
 }, {
     "pitanje": "Ko je komponovao operu 'Samson I Dalila'",
     "ponudjeno": ["Žorž Bize", "Ðuzepe Verdi", "Kamij Sen-Sans"],
     "tacan": 2
 }, {
     "pitanje": "Ko je autor satiricnih pripovedaka 'Danga', 'Kraljevic Marko po drugi put medu Srbima' i drugih",
     "ponudjeno": ["Milovan Glišic", "Laza Lazarevic", "Radoje Domanovic"],
     "tacan": 2
 }, {
     "pitanje": "Koje godine je u Atini održana prva Olimpijada 'modernog doba'.",
     "ponudjeno": ["1896.", "1898.", "1900."],
     "tacan": 0
 }]
```

};

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: pitalice" class="divPitalice">
<div class="divPitanje">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: pitanje" style="width: 600px" />
    <div data-bind="foreach: ponudjeno">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data" />
        <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: $parentContext.$index, value: $index }, checked: $parent.tacan" />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see changes to the big text boxes are propagated to the view model nicely.

But if you change smaller text boxes and click save those changes are not saved in view model.

Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ko.mapping` plugin maps arrays and objects only (they become observableArray's and observable's respectively). Your answer arrays are plain strings and not considered as objects.

Just convert your string arrays to object arrays:

```
var dataObj = {
    "pitalice": [{
        "pitanje": "Kako se zove rezultat koji se dobija deljenjem dva broja",
        "ponudjeno": [ { text: "Kolicnik" }, { text: "Suma" }, { text: "Proizvod" } ],
        "tacan": 0
    },
    .....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a28aP/11/

Comment: Is there any solution without changing the model ?

Comment: Yes, you can, by specifying extra mapping options (e.g. [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a28aP/12/) does so). Go through the [mapping documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for more details.

Comment: It's possible but definitely `ko.mapping` is not an option in this case. You have to write own customized model mapper which would correctly handle plain string arrays. @Jeroen, this trick works but the output JSON will also include properties added by custom constructor.

Comment: huh.. not a good solution. So I am going to transform the models.
Incredible that ko.mapping does not support this :/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the issue is, it probably has something to do with observableArrays but [heres a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9N6nP/) with a workaround.

I basically wrapped your array items in objects like this:

```
 var dataObj = {
 "pitalice": [{
     "pitanje": "Kako se zove rezultat koji se dobija deljenjem dva broja",
     "ponudjeno": [{ name: "Kolicnik" }, { name: "Suma"}, { name: "Proizvod"}],
     "tacan": 0
 }, {
     "pitanje": "Limonit je ruda",
     "ponudjeno": [{ name: "Aluminijuma"}, { name: "Olova"}, { name: "Gvožda"}],
     "tacan": 2
 }, {
     "pitanje": "Ko je komponovao operu 'Samson I Dalila'",
     "ponudjeno": [{ name: "Žorž Bize"}, { name: "Ðuzepe Verdi"}, { name: "Kamij Sen-Sans"}],
     "tacan": 2
 }, {
     "pitanje": "Ko je autor satiricnih pripovedaka 'Danga', 'Kraljevic Marko po drugi put medu Srbima' i drugih",
     "ponudjeno": [{ name: "Milovan Glišic"}, { name: "Laza Lazarevic"}, { name: "Radoje Domanovic"}],
     "tacan": 2
 }, {
     "pitanje": "Koje godine je u Atini održana prva Olimpijada 'modernog doba'.",
     "ponudjeno": [{ name: "1896."}, { name: "1898."}, { name: "1900."}],
     "tacan": 0
 }]
};
```

And changed $data to $data.name in the HTML:

```
<h2>Pitalice</h2>
  <div data-bind="foreach: pitalice" class="divPitalice">
  <div class="divPitanje">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: pitanje" style="width: 600px" />
    <div data-bind="foreach: ponudjeno">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.name" />
        <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: $parentContext.$index, value: $index}, checked: $parent.tacan" />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="alert(ko.mapping.toJSON(window.kViewModel));">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

It doesn't track the changes to the values because they aren't objects or properties, but just a list of strings.  So there isn't anything to update.  I forked your jsfiddle and changed it from a list of strings to a list of objects with a name property and it updated correctly.  Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyjmeyers/WKu94/)  and an example below:

```
 {
     "pitanje": "Kako se zove rezultat koji se dobija deljenjem dva broja",
     "ponudjeno": [{name:"Kolicnik"}, {name:"Suma"}, {name:"Proizvod"}],
     "tacan": 0
 },
```